# go how to implement python binascii.unhexlify method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, go

In my company there is a system written in python and I want to reimplement it using golang.

## Question

Python `binascii.unhexlify` seems complex, and I don't know hot to implement it in go.

Comment: It's just converting from hex to binary. Every two hex digits is an 8-bit byte (256 possible values).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 sorry, `binascii.unhexlify` is simple

Comment: In case this isn't an exercise, production code should of course use the standard library: https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/hex/#Decode.

Comment: @Peter tks, It's what i want

Answer (score -1):

`binascii.unhexlify` method is simple enough.
It's just converting from hex to binary. Every two hex digits is an 8-bit byte (256 possible values).
here is my code

```
func unhexlify(str string) []byte {
    res := make([]byte, 0)
    for i := 0; i < len(str); i+=2 {
        x, _ := strconv.ParseInt(str[i:i+2], 16, 32)
        res = append(res, byte(x))
    }
    return res
}
```

---

**I should use the library**

```
func ExampleDecodeString() {
    const s = "48656c6c6f20476f7068657221"
    decoded, err := hex.DecodeString(s)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%s\n", decoded)

    // Output:
    // Hello Gopher!
}
```